# how to create new Session in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Dear I have a two function and use the session to pass values from one function to another but it shows null when I get session value in another function here is my function

```
 public function getValues(Request $request)
   {

    $activity_id=$request->activity_id;
    $users=User::all();
    $data = SessionEvent::where('activity_id',$activity_id)->get();
    Session()->put('activity_id',$activity_id);
    Session()->save();

       return  view('sessionevent.index',compact('data','activity_id'));

   }
 
    public function create()
    {
        
        $activity_id=Session()->get('activity_id');
        dd($activity_id);
        return View::make('sessionevent.create',compact('activity_id'));
    }
```

i just want to pass $activity_id to create.blade.php page if there is another smart solution please let me know i will search in google

Comment: Does `dd(Session()->get('activity_id'));` work after `Session()->put('activity_id',$activity_id)` ?

Comment: @nice_dev thank you for your quick reply it works dd(Session()->get('activity_id')); and here is the result after dd "d4f15dae-9d95-4c2b-9a39-cf7281b4fb04"

Comment: Ok, then this cannot happen. If session is stored properly and gets correct value after printing, there is no reason it won't work in `create` method. Can you explain why do you need to add `Session()->save()` explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
$request->session()->put('key', $value);
```

and then to get the session

```
$sessionValue = $request->session()->get('key');
```

for regenerating the session

```
$request->session()->regenerate();
```

and if you want to remove session data

```
$request->session()->invalidate();
```

and for deleting session data

```
$request->session()->forget('key');
```

[laravel sessions documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#regenerating-the-session-id)

make sure that the `$value` is of type String.